# How to store action/events logs and there variables in a database

Tags: sql, reactjs, database, express, prisma

I'm looking for a way to store events/interactions in a SQL database using prisma ORM and display them in a React frontend.

By events, I mean:

- Contact U has called
- Employee X has updated contract #345785
- Contact Z has accepted offer #697686
- An email with subject 'New offer available' has been sent to contact B'
- Employee F has been blocked by employee K
- A new comment has been added to task #567865 by employee C

So far I have created a model for an event with the following properties:

- `action_type`: The type of the action: meeting, email, call, user_management, ...
- `message_code`: A code which refers to a template stored in a json file used for translations. For example `email_to_contact` is stored as `An email with subject '{{email_subject}}' has been sent to {{contact_name}}`.
- `created_at`: A timestamp to know when the event took place.

Now I'm trying to find a way to store the actual data needed for the templates in a way where it can be used to fill in in the templates on the frontend but also to filter the events so for example only the events related to contact x are shown on their detail page and the templates parts are clickable so it navigates to the detail page of a contact/employee/offer/...

Anyone who can give me some direction in how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using a JSON data field in your Event model to store miscellaneous data relevant to the event, in a flexible schema-less way. For instance, the data field could contain {email_subject: '...', contact_name: '...'} for an email event, `{task_id: '...', comment: '...'} for a comment event, etc.

Comment: @NurulSundarani Yes but wouldn't that be hard to filter the events of a specific employee, contact, offer number, etc. since it's a JSON object?